# How to input YES in a batch file automatically?

Tags: batch-file

I am uninstalling Citrix client using a batch file. The batch initiates the uninstall successfuly, but I need to input YES (for confirmation) automatically. How can I do this in the batch file?

Comment: Do you knwo what's asking? maybe a snippet of the batch file. How you automate it depends on what you're automating.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

> msiexec /x mps.msi /L*v c:\output.log CTX_MF_FORCE_SUBSYSTEM_UNINSTALL=Yes

**Note:** mps.msi is the name and location of the msi package.

Answer (score 0):

You use `echo` to send `yes` to the application. Here's a small demo:

```
echo yes | findstr "^"
```

Comment: it is an exe file. echo yes | ... is not working here is the command I am using:  echo yes | C:\WINDOWS\system32\ctxsetup.exe /uninst -y C:\PROGRA~1\Citrix\icaweb32\uninst.inf
.